# Result is not stored after call to str.upper

Tags: python-3.6

So I am working with the string method `s.upper()`, but when it executes it does not convert the whole sentence to uppercase. I am wondering if my understanding is wrong or I am doing something wrong.

I tried using the `s.lower` method and it gave me the same display with nothing changed.

Here is my code:

```
foods = ['soup', 'waffle', 'pizza']
for food in foods:
    food[0].upper()
print(foods[0], foods[1], foods[2])
```

The code displays :

```
soup waffle pizza
```

when I expected

```
SOUP WAFFLE PIZZA
```

Comment: `food[0].upper()` returns the uppercase variant, but doesn't do anything with it. You need to do something like: `foods = [food.upper() for food in foods]`

Comment: Okay. So in that case why does it not return one uppercase or an uppercase for the whole string? I am asking because i am trying to understand how it really works

Comment: As bphi said, it does, except you are not doing anything with it. The return value is thrown away the second it is obtained. Try his code and you'll see it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that should elucidate the problem:

```
food = 'Soup'
food.upper()
print(food)
>>> 'Soup'
```

When you called `food.upper()`, it returned `SOUP`, but you didn't do anything with the result. Instead, you need to assign the result to something.

```
food = 'Soup'
food = food.upper()
print(food)
>>> 'SOUP'
```

This time, since you assigned the result of the call to `food.upper()` back to the variable food, it now has the value `SOUP` which you see when you print it.

Comment: Oh i get it now. so it has to be assigned back for it to work. Thanks so much @bphi